# Webpack: How can I combine two completely separate bundles using dynamic bundling

Tags: reactjs, build, webpack, webpack-2

I have spent a lot of time looking into this, but to no avail.  I am aware of how code splitting and dynamic bundling works in Webpack using the `import` promise API.

Howevr, my use case is that I have two completely separate bundles, generated separately using different webpack builds.  To give you perspective, I am building React components and there is a requirement to dynamically load a react component into the page that has been compiled in a different process.  Is this possible in react?  I do have control over both webpack builds, so I can exclude dependencies, etc.

**Update:** I just looked at Vue.js, and how it allows developers to register Vue.js components and then reference them later in the code.  I could potentially load my Vue.js component scripts before my page script.  I'm trying to see if I can do something similar in React.

Comment: Just to supply the docs: https://webpack.js.org/guides/author-libraries/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Did I understand you correctly: you have essentially got

1. a library of custom React components (built by Webpack build #1)
2. a React app that needs to use some (all) of these components (built by Webpack build #2, totally separate from #1)

?

If yes, then read on.

The *"Is this possible in react?"* question should instead be *"Is this possible in Webpack?"*, and the answer is *"Yes"*. The following is tested with Webpack 2, but should also work with v.1.

Let's call your projects `Lib` (your React component library) and `App` (the library consumer).

In the `Lib` project:

1. Create an entry point file, say `index.js`, that exports all the custom React components like this:

   ```
   import {Button} from './button';
   import {DatePicker} from './DatePicker';
   import {TextBox} from './textBox';

   export const MyComponentLib = {
       Button,
       DatePicker,
       TextBox
   };
   ```
2. Update `webpack.config.js` to make the project's bundle a UMD library (could also be 'var'), and set the entry point to the above `index.js` file. Doing so will make your library available via a global variable named `MyComponentLib` (the name comes from the `export` above) in the consuming app later on:

   ```
    ...
    output: {
        path: './dist',
        filename: 'mylib.bundle.js',
        libraryTarget: 'umd'
    },
    ...
    entry: './index.js',
    ...
   ```

On to the `App` project:

1. In the `index.html` file you will have two `<script>` tags: one for `mylib.bundle.js` (the output of the `Lib` project), and another for the bundle of the `App` project itself. You might have more bundles (app, vendor etc.), I'm just simplifying things here.
2. Update `webpack.config.js` to mark the component library as external dependency. Here, `MyComponentLib` is, again, the name of the global variable the library is available at, and `myComponents` is the name to use in `import` statements:

   ```
   ...
   externals: {
       myComponents: 'MyComponentLib'
   }, 
   ...
   ```

Now, in `App` you can import a component like this:

```
import {DatePicker} from 'myComponents';
```

This will dynamically load DatePicker from the component library at run time via the global variable.

Bonus: if you use `eslint`, you don't want it to complain about missing modules that you know are external; add this to your `.eslintrc`:

```
...
"settings": {
      "import/core-modules": ["myComponents"]
},
...
```

Comment: Is there a way of doing this dynamically? Like for example, we have a bunch of component libraries and we want to use only one.
My use case would be that the name of the component I want to use comes from props. Then I'd load asynchronously the .js and work with it. I don't wanna be compiling the main project's source each time I create a new library.

Comment: @JesúsFuentes - take a look at [dll-plugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/dll-plugin/).

Comment: @Eliran Malka That doesn't fit what I want. Anyway, I'm testing https://github.com/muicss/loadjs

Comment: I finally succeed, @EliranMalka.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46845792/dynamic-import-with-not-bundled-file/