# Dynamic import with not bundled file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, ecmascript-6, dynamic-import

I have a React project bundled with Webpack.

I have a component that I want it to render components Dynamically. In my case, the path of the component comes from props.

Also, these components are not bundled in my project .js file; they are external React components/libaries.

I've tried the Dynamic ES6 import:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
    if(nextProps.pagesData && this.props.pagesData !== nextProps.pagesData && nextProps.pagesData.get('cards').count() > 0){

        // Getting the first card from the Immutable object
        let card = nextProps.pagesData.getIn(['cards', 0]);

        // Getting the cardType which can be: '/path/index.js'
        let cardType = card.get('card_type');

        // ES6 Dynamic import
        import(cardType)
            .then(module => {
                 this.setState({ asyncCard: module.default });
             })
    }
}
```

This doesn't work because import needs a static route.

Then I've tried with require:

```
let dynamicComponent = require(cardType);
```

Which doesn't work because (I assume) Webpack tries to find it into the main bundle.

Is this even possible to do?

**Update**: It looks like this can work (cardType is 'index.js' - a React component):

```
import(`/home/user/_apps/module/react-module/lib/${cardType}`)
```

Webpack creates a different bundle (chunk) including the code of index.js and all it's dependencies.

But this doesn't really solve my original question.

**Edit 2**: The import from above actually ignores the last var and Webpack makes chunks of every file inside /lib.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally came up with a solution.

[LoadJS](https://github.com/muicss/loadjs) library. You can use [$script](https://github.com/ded/script.js/) also.

**Library project** (external components):
index.js:

```
import App from './App';

export const MyComponentLib = {
   App
};
```

App.jsx:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

export default class App extends Component {
   render() {
      return (
         <div className="App">
             <header className="App-header">
                 <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
                 <h1 className="App-title">Welcome to React</h1>
             </header>
             <p className="App-intro">
                 To get started, edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
             </p>
         </div>
      );
   }
}
```

In the library's webpack config file (production), added:

```
libraryTarget: 'umd',
```

**Main project** file (main.js):

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
    if(nextProps.pagesData && this.props.pagesData !== nextProps.pagesData && nextProps.pagesData.get('cards').count() > 0){

        // Getting all asyncCards from state
        let currentCards = cloneDeep(this.state.asyncCards);

        // Immutable "get" function - getting cards from nextProps
        nextProps.pagesData.get('cards').forEach(card => {

            // Getting card_type, which in this case is the filename
            let cardType = card.get('card_type');

            // Do we have this card already in the state object?
            if(!hasIn(currentCards, cardType)) {

                // AsyncLoading the card file
                loadjs(`/custom/1/${cardType}.js`, cardType, {
                    success: () => {

                        // Cloning App function (the component)
                        currentCards[cardType] = window.MyComponentLib.App.bind({});

                        this.setState({
                            asyncCards: currentCards
                        })
                    }
                })
            }
        })
    }
}
```